# Slide up animation from line

Tags: css, animation

What would be the best way to animate the text to slide up from the line? Basically I'm trying to get the top text to slide up from the line and the bottom text to slide down from the line if they would be hidden inside the line I suppose.

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at animation and transform

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  height: 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: max-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: linear-gradient( currentcolor,currentcolor) center 85%/ 80% 2px no-repeat
}

p+p {
  background: none;
}

p span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translatey(4em);
  animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
}

p+p span {
  transform: translatey(-4em);
}

@keyframes slide {
  to {
    transform: translatey(0em)
  }
}


/* demo */

body {
background:#333;
color: #eee;
margin:0;
min-height:100vh;
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
font-size:3vw;
justify-content:center;
}
}
```

```html
<p><span>Some text here to slide up</span></p>
<p><span>Some text here to slide down</span></p>
```